# How to declare module public type definition for NPM in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I created a npm package (https://github.com/d6u/observe-object-path). It is written in Typescript. It has a build step to compile it down to ES5 so any JavaScript environment can consume it (https://github.com/d6u/observe-object-path/blob/master/package.json#L39-L41).

1. Since the module is already written in Typescript. Is it possible to automatically generate a `.d.ts` file for my package, so people using Typescript can use it with minimum or no configuration?
2. If automatic generate is not possible, what's the best place to place the `.d.ts` file, under `ts` directory (which apparently is what Rx 4 is doing https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/ts)?

Answer (score 1):

To generate .d.ts files for your project you must enable the **declaration** option in the compiler configuration.

An example with **tsconfig.json**.

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out. If you update your answer to follow those steps, I can accept it: 1. All it matters is the `-d` option of `tsc` or `declaration` property of the tsconfig.json. 2. Then you have to add `"typings": "lib/index.d.ts"` to point to whatever type definition of your index file in your package.json (lib/index.d.ts here is just an example). 3. I haven't figure out how to make ambient (or nested dependencies to work).

Comment: @Daiwei if you found an answer that better suits your question you can just post it yourself. :)